# How long should you wait before applying for an internal transfer?

Tags: internal-transfer

I've been in my current position for 3 months. When I interviewed, I was told this was a great department. Unfortunately, I've now found out it's drama filled, and it's not a pleasant work environment.

I'm scared to go to HR for fear of retaliation. I want to wait for the appropriate time frame, keep my head down and do a great job, so that I don't look bad when applying for internal transfer.

I want to know what that appropriate time frame is to apply for an internal transfer.

Comment: It very much depends on the company (and how much you've actually contributed thus far). Some have no problem with you moving no matter how new you are, others have a minimum amount of time before you can move, but most probably just have some vague unwritten guidelines about it. If you're trying to avoid bad blood with the department, you should probably wait at least a year, but there'll probably be bad blood either way if they're those sorts of people (not to mention that they might make moving harder, if possible).

Comment: Are you sure that's a department-specific problem? Cancer has this habit of spreading.

Comment: Yes it's a pretty BIG place and I've been doing my research (discretely) and I have found out this department has a group w/in it that has a very BAD reputation.

Answer (score 2):

There's no universally accepted time frame to apply for internal transfer. Check your company policy on the minimum time period that an employee should spend in their current role before they become eligible for internal transfer.

If there's no such policy, the acceptable time frame would depend on many factors, such as how long you can tolerate being in your current role and how soon your current manager can let you leave.

Nonetheless, before going for internal transfer, you should discuss your issues with your manager and see how you can work together to resolve them, or at least make them less undesirable. No job will be perfect, and you would need to deal with a lot of undesirable situations (and people) if you want to go far in your career. Jumping at the first instance of a problem wouldn't help you much.

Comment: Oh they are aware of the issues, but I'm pretty sure they fear retaliation as well.